# Hibernate: Handling Multiple Transactions?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying and very curious to understand Hibernate. If two or more users try to insert something at the same time in the same table, using the same form from different PCs,

- how will Hibernate manage this transaction?
- Which record will get saved first?
- Will it apply a lock?
- How does it works internally?

Answer (score 1):

Lets name the users A and B.

User A's request would update the db via a transaction and at the end of that transaction, the changes will be committed to the db by default.(You could change this of course)

User B's request would also be executed in another transaction and at the end this will also be committed to the db.

When committing to the database, there will be locking for concurrency control and it depends on the database and the hibernate configuration as well.

- Optimistic Locking

When using optimistic locking, you map a special attribute (a number, a timestamp) as a version (so you actually have a column for it). This version is read when you retrieve an entity and included in the where clause during an update and incremented by Hibernate.

- Pessimistic Locking

When using pessimistic locking, Hibernate locks a record for your exclusive use until you have finished with it

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate provides Versions based solution (Optimistic lock).

```
@Version
```

annotation could be used.

The field of entity could be just int or timestamp (with corresponding column in the entity table). When an entity is read version is retrieved. On save version is checked and if it was changed hibernate prevent the DB change.

Read [this](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2012/11/02/version-based-optimistic-concurrency-control-in-jpahibernate/) or [this](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/versioning-optimistic-locking-in-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate can perform automatic optimistic concurrency control for you. It can automatically detect if a concurrent modification occurred during user think time. Check for this at the end of the conversation.which is called Automatic Versioning. Transaction management will take care of these we don't need to worry